# Button doesn't show on top of Maps Activity

Tags: google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to add a button on top of Map Activity, in the layout.
I just want to show a button over the map layout, but I tried different layouts, Constraint, Relative... and nothing works. I also tried to put the map fragment in XML before and after the button inside a relative layout, and yet it did nothing, it shows only the map.

I resized the map and even removed the map layout, and still the map shows in full screen.

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="336dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.parse.starter.RidersActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your fragment has fixed size. you have to changed it with "0dp" in ConstraintLayout. and you have to define proper constraint.

Comment: i also tried to change the size of the fragment to 0 dp, but no sign of the button on the screen! i can only see the full map...i cannot even resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the problem, i accidentally created 2 similar activities and i was editing the wrong activity, that's why there were no errors. Thanks everybody who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say the orientation for constraintLayout. Just make your fragment sizes `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and
       `android:layout_height="match_parent"` , add button and constraint it to your fragment:

You don't need to say the orientation for constraintLayout. Just make your fragment sizes `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and
    `android:layout_height="match_parent"` , add button and constraint it to your fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks like this :

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried it,...but still doesn't work! the preview is as you posted, but on my device it shows only the map without button.

Comment: In that case,give your buttom some elevation, swap or put the button above the fragment in the xml(just do it on my example)

Answer (score 0):

Just Make your Fragment `height and weight` attribute `match_parent`

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="652dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope its work for you